# Survey Monkey Custom Variable Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, surveymonkey

I have created a survey on Survey Monkey. And added a custom variable. The collector is a weblink appending the custom variable to it.

I have a c# project through which I want to check if a user has completed the survey or not. If someone has completed the survey then they are redirected to the homepage and if not then they are redirected to the survey page. I'm passing the OrgID in my redirect if users have not completed the survey.

I want to be able to check if this Org_ID is in the list of responses. I'm able to get the bulk responses in my Get request But is there a way I can just check directly if this OrgID exists in my completed list.
Bulk Request: https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/1234/responses/bulk

Comment: A solution I was seeing is using javascript to read the json response and search the response for the Org ID. Trying to do this method to c#. Should work. Will test this.

Comment: I was going to do this, but that would mean going through each page of of responses to check. Seems very suboptimial.